# Trying to instantiate a class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment that is not a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

as in the title:

> Trying to instantiate a class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment that is not a Fragment

I've got a two activities. Both have following code with different ids and reference to different navigation graphs

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/splash_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_splash"/>
```

When i comment above code application runs ok. In First activity i can navigate to second activity and app works just fine. When i uncomment above code - app crashes

Any help?

Answer (score 29):

I was extending `Activity` but i should `AppCompatActivity`.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: For those who dont want an actionbar which `AppCompatActivity` adds, `FragmentActivity` can be also be used...